# SQL Server Migration Assistant issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, plsql, sql-server-migration-assi

I'll start off by saying I'm in no way a PL/SQL or T-SQL expert and I only really know the basics but I have been asked to undergo a project to migrate about 1,700 PL/SQL procedure packages to T-SQL. Even if I knew PL/SQL the best way is using an automated tool to at least cover the majority of the translation. I've been using Microsoft's SQL Server Migration Assistant. After reading [this article.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/archive/2010/09/21/how-to-convert-individual-statement-using-ssma.aspx) I Am under the impression it is possible to convert single pieces of PL/SQL.

When I'm migrating schema's its giving me 3 errors every time. The same 3 errors. And basically it doesn't do the migrating at all. It just seems to comment the whole thing out?

[image: The errors I'm getting]

I just want to know what is going wrong and why it is not migrating. From the second error my impression is that it is not converting because it is looking for ''stage_sendup_nb' but that doesn't exist on the database because I just pasted the SQL in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Unparsed SQL" means that it didn't recognize the statement you tried to convert. Most likely CREATE PROCEDURE is not supported for SQL statements. When you have a procedure to convert it's better to find it in Procedures and convert from there. "Snippet" conversion is very limited, it's designed to convert a statement or two, usually some specific query you want to try on the migrated DB (e.g. SELECT or UPDATE).

Any conversion of SQL (including procedures and SQL statements) relies on proper metadata available in Oracle. So you have to connect to Oracle database with all referenced tables, procedures and so on to convert even one procedure. In that way SSMA knows details about the referenced objects.

Comment: Perfect answer, that covered everything I was curious about thank you.